# Multiprocessing with Screen and Bash

Tags: python, bash, multiprocessing, numerical-methods

Running a python script on different nodes at school using SSH.  Each node has 8 cores. I use GNU Screen to be able to detach from a single process.

Is it more desirable to:

1. Run several different sessions of screen.
2. Run a single screen process and use `&` in a bash terminal.

Are they equivalent?

I am not sure if my experiments are poorly coded and taking an inordinate amount of time (very possible) OR my choice to use 1. is slowing the process down considerably.  Thank you!

Comment: As far as I know, both solutions are equivalent:

Option 1 simply sends the command to the background, and option 2 keeps the command running on the foreground of each "virtual console". I'd look for the problem in the code.

Comment: define "desirable". Convenience? Performance? As far as performance goes, the two are identical. If you have poor performance then you're either over-subscribing the machine (either because you run too much at once or someone else is also using it, see `top`) or your code needs work.

Comment: If these are interactive programs, you want to keep track of their outputs separately or you want them to continue if you loose your session, screen is the better choice.

Comment: The third alternative (unless this is alternative 1 and I misunderstood it) is to use a single screen session and multiple windows (shell sessions) inside that screen instance. But this doesn't affect the fact that for any heavy process the overhead of even the worst possible option here is unlikely to matter.

Comment: Have a look at GNU Parallel - it is extremely capable at getting the most out of multi-core CPUs... https://www.biostars.org/p/63816/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `bash` I imagine you're doing something like this (assuming `/home` is under network mount):

```
#!/bin/bash    

for i in {1..$NUM_NODES}
do
    ssh node$i 'python /home/ryan/my_script.py' &
done
```

Launching this script from behind a single `screen` will work fine. Starting up several sessions of `screen` provides no performance gains but adds in the extra complication of starting multiple screens.

Keep in mind that there are much better ways to distribute load across a cluster (e.g. if someone else is using up all of node7 you'd want a way to detect that and send your job elsewhere). Most clusters I've worked with have [Torque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TORQUE_Resource_Manager), [Maui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maui_Cluster_Scheduler) or the `qsub` command installed. I suggest giving those a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would think they are about the same.  I would prefer screen just because I have an easier time managing it.  Depending on the scripts usage, that could also have some effect on time to process.