# Python Multiprocessing and Serializing Data

Tags: python, io, daemon, python-multiprocessing

I am running a script on a school computer using the `multiprocessing` module.  I am serializing the data frequently.  It can be summarized by the code below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time, pickle

def simulation(j):
    data = []
    for k in range(10):
        data.append(k)
        time.sleep(1)
        file = open('data%d.pkl'%j, 'wb')
        pickle.dump(data, file)
        file.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []
    processes.append(mp.Process(target = simulation, args = (1,) ))
    processes.append(mp.Process(target = simulation, args = (2,) ))
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

So when I actually run my code for many more simulations and what I imagine to be more intensive varied tasks, I get the following error: `IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error` usually preceded by `file.open(...)` or `file.close()`.

My questions:

- How do I fix this error in my script?
- What does this error mean for a python newcomer?  References appreciated.

Some more notes about my procedure:

- Instead of setting the multiprocess attribute `daemon` to be `True`, I use screen to run the script and then detach.  This allows me also to disconnect without worrying about my script stopping.
- This seemed to be a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409897/ioerror-input-output-error-when-printing) about printing using the `subprocess` module.  I did not explicitly use daemon as I said, so not sure if this will help.
- This usually happens after running for about a day and occurs on different processes at different times.

Comment: At the suggestion of a friend, I used the bash command `nohup` instead of `screen` to decrease the number of 'layers' between me and the kernel.  He said roughly speaking this might increase the chances that this error doesn't crop up.  Anyways, it still does...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program looks pretty good.  In this case `IOError` just means "bad things happened." The entire set of simulated data became to large for the Python process, so it exited with the mysterious message.

A couple improvements in the following version:

- Once some data has been produced, *append* it to a data file, then
  zap it from memory. The program should have roughly the same RAM use over time, rather than using up more and more, then crashing.
- Conveniently, if a file is a concatenation of `pickle` objects, we
  can easily print out each one later for further examination. Example code shown.

Have fun!

### source

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import glob, time, pickle, sys

def simulation(j):
    for k in range(10):
        datum = {'result': k}
        time.sleep(1)
        with open('data%d.pkl'%j, 'ab') as dataf:
            pickle.dump(datum, dataf)

def show():
    for datname in glob.glob('data*.pkl'):
        try:
            print '*'*8, datname
            with open(datname, 'rb') as datf:
                while True:
                    print pickle.load(datf)
        except EOFError:
            pass

def do_sim():
    processes = []
    processes.append(mp.Process(target = simulation, args = (1,) ))
    processes.append(mp.Process(target = simulation, args = (2,) ))
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if '--show' in sys.argv:
        show()
    else:
        do_sim()
```

### output of "python ./msim.py --show"

```
******** data2.pkl
{'result': 0}
{'result': 1}
{'result': 2}
{'result': 3}
{'result': 4}
{'result': 5}
{'result': 6}
{'result': 7}
{'result': 8}
{'result': 9}
******** data1.pkl
{'result': 0}
{'result': 1}
{'result': 2}
{'result': 3}
{'result': 4}
{'result': 5}
{'result': 6}
{'result': 7}
{'result': 8}
{'result': 9}
```

Comment: THANK YOU very, very, VERY much for answering!  I suspected some problems with memory. Still having trouble tracking this down, but I will check this again.


I am using Matlab-like numpy implementations everywhere, so I have lots of code where I initialize a large array (~10^3), store data in individual array entries, and finally dump the array using pickle after each iteration.  Use a dictionary to store different arrays by name.  Don't know if I can alter all my code without a serious time investment.  Any other fun workarounds, are appreciated, but again, so happy you answered.